# How to invoke apache module by default for every request?

Tags: c, apache, apache2, apache2.2, apr

I developed an apache module in which I am collecting some data from a request. How to call my module for every request by default in Apache? I wrote my module in C.

My Module declaration code

```
module AP_MODULE_DECLARE_DATA helloworld_module = {
STANDARD20_MODULE_STUFF,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
helloworld_hooks
};
```

this is my module hook code

```
static void helloworld_hooks(apr_pool_t *pool)
{
ap_hook_handler(helloworld_handler, NULL, NULL, APR_HOOK_FIRST);
}
```

this is my module main function code

```
static int helloworld_handler(request_rec *r)
{
  // here I am implementing my all functionality.
}
```

http.conf file settings

```
 <Location /helloworld> 
 SetHandler helloworld 
 </Location>
```

I want every time request reach to apache my module should invoke automatically.

Comment: I suggest to put something from your code here to illustrate the problem. It is important to show, that you really have something which requires a little fix only.

Comment: @peterh I have added my code. Please have a look and suggest solution.

Comment: I don't know the apr enough well. Is your apache config okay? Can you surely see your module in the list of your apache config by a well-directed apachectl command?

Comment: In my http.conf file I gave location for my module and when I am hitting that location My module is working but I want it should work for all URL by default      '<Location /helloworld>
SetHandler helloworld
</Location>'